# Which urllib attribute should I use instead of urllib.quote() in Pycharm Edition 4.5.4?

Tags: python, pycharm

I used this in pycharm 4.5.4:

```
url_base += urllib.quote()
```

It gave an error:

> AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'quote'.

Which attribute should I use here?

Comment: pycharm is irrelevant, what version of python you are using is.

Answer (score 2):

I take it you are using Python 3, so you should change it to `urllib.parse.quote`

Here is a  [link to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote)